# Dropdown (selection) in MVC PartialView does not update text after changing value by jQuery

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile, partial-views

I have a MVC 2 / jQuery mobile application.

On my main view I have a list that is sortable. The sort works by url parameter `sortorder`. the dropdown with which you can change the sorting is in a partial view that looks like this:

```
<div class="ui-select">
    <select name="sortSelect" id="sortSelect" data-mini="true">
        <option value="opt1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="opt2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="opt3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Then I have a jQuery that checks whether the dropdown is changed. On change it adds or changes url `sort` parameter with new dropdown value and redirects to new url:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#sortSelect').change(function () {
        var sortOrder = $('#sortSelect').val();
        var url = document.URL;
        if (url.indexOf("sortorder=") > -1)
            url = url.replace(/sortorder=[^&]+/, "sortorder=" + sortOrder);
        else
            url = url + "&sortorder=" + sortOrder;
        window.location.replace(url);
    });
});
```

As there are a few other parameters before the sortorder it is ok that is added with &.

To set the correct value from the url when the page is newly loaded I have following jQuery (function gup reads value from url):

```
$('#sortSelect').ready(function () {
    var sortorder = gup('sortorder');
    if (sortorder != '')
        $('#sortSelect').val(sortorder);
}
```

There is the problem: if I load the site and change the `sortorder` by dropdown, everything works so far. The page is newly loaded with new url parameter and newly sorted list. even the dropdown value is set correctly (I checked this by `alert($('#sortSelect').val()`, but the dropdown text is the old one. If I press F5 the site refreshes, and the dropdown has its correct text...

Any ideas how i can solve the problem? Or what is the problem at all?

Comment: i found the answer on my own. as expected i have to refresh the select (dropdown) with ***$("#sortSelect").selectmenu("refresh");*** like this:

    $('#sortSelect').ready(function () {
        var sortorder = gup('sortorder');
        if (sortorder != '')
            $('#sortSelect').val(unescape(sortorder));
        $("#sortSelect").selectmenu("refresh");
    });

sometimes, easy problems take some time ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on my own. As expected I have to refresh the select (dropdown) with `$("#sortSelect").selectmenu("refresh");` like this:

```js
$('#sortSelect').ready(function () { 
    var sortorder = gup('sortorder'); 
    if (sortorder != '') $('#sortSelect').val(unescape(sortorder));
    $("#sortSelect").selectmenu("refresh");
});
```

sometimes, easy problems take some time ;)